# MS Excel: generate a table with the number of rows depending on the input variables

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, automation, pivot-table, microsoft-dynamics

So I want to make a matlab/r-like tool in excel that mimics more code driven calculations than the more common excel worksheet applications typically contain

This workbook should contain:

1. input sheet
2. calculations sheet
3. output sheet

I tried VBA, but I don't like it and also I have no experience coding in it (it takes too long for what I want to get)

So, my next try is to make it happen directly in Excel, without VBA.

For that goal, I need to:

1. Create a table in the calculation sheet with the number of rows depending on the input variables given by the user in the input sheet.
2. Fill up the cells of that table based on the input variables of the user, together with some pre-defined formules on what to put in those cells

E.g. user input 1 = 4, user input 2 = 6

Code =>> Create table with 4 rows and 4 columns, start from 6 in most left/top cell and multiple  by 2 in each column, than before going to the next row, subtract two and do the same, etc.

so, output would be in this case

```
6 12 24 48 

4 8 16 32

2 4 8 16

0 0 0 0
```

just as an example

You could easily program this if you knew the number of rows/columns beforehand, but what if you don't, and you want to create such a table?

Is this possible somehow? I don't want the end user to be doing anything else than providing the input values.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I'm not asking for solutions, I'm asking for suggestions. I can add the VBA code that I tried, but it's nowhere near a solution, and as indicated here, I'm not willing to continue to try to get a solution in VBA, so I don't see the relevance. I have not tried something in excel yet.(without VBA), as I have no clue how to start.

I don't get your closing warning: how does my question differ from any other question posted here?

Comment: A formula solution will depend on what version of excel you have, newer versions have various array formulas, maybe in your case you want `MAKEARRAY`. `SEQUENCE`, `BYROW` and `BYCOL` are other options to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA solution. Assuming inputs are on B1 and B2

```
Public Sub CreateTable()

    Dim rownum, colnum, startnum, z, multi As Integer
    rownum = Range("B1").Value  'number of rows
    colnum = Range("B1").Value  'number of columns
    
    startnum = Range("B2").Value  'starting value
    
    z = 3  'third row.
    
    For x = 1 To rownum
        multi = 1   'use to multiply the starting value
        For y = 67 To 66 + colnum  '67 represents code for C
            
            Range(Chr(y) & z).Value = startnum * multi 'Set the value on the table
            multi = multi * 2
            
        Next y
        z = z + 1
        startnum = startnum - 2
    Next x

End Sub
```

**Demo**

[image]